# HP ALM OTA get Requirement for Test

Tags: alm

I need the Requirement ID for a Test.
The only code sample I found does this for a Bug:
http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/ota/topic157.html

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Method `GetCoverList()` in the `Test` object which gives you a list of `Req` objects which have a property `ID`.